# Is the Integrated Information Theory of Consciousness Falsifiable?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind

I was reading an article on [Integrated Information Theory of Consciousness](https://philosophynow.org/issues/121/The_Integrated_Information_Theory_of_Consciousness) in the latest edition of [Philosophy Now](https://philosophynow.org).

The article says:

> IIT has radical implications. If IIT is true, we could in principle build a ‘consciousness-meter’ that tells us whether any system is conscious, and to what level: from comatose patients to infants; from simple animals and plants to robots and next generation AI.

But I'm having a hard time understanding how IIT is [falsifiable as a theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability) and in what way IIT solves [the problem of other minds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/) in a such a way that we could demonstrate that e.g. robots are conscious, intelligent agents.

Anyone knows how IIT can be put to the test to answer these kind of questions?

Comment: Wikipedia gives a somewhat more serious description of IIT, with mathematical formalization and [comments on experimental work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory#Related_Experimental_Work):"*IIT can be used to explain why some brain regions, such as the cerebellum do not appear to contribute to consciousness, despite their size and/or functional importance. IIT can also help to explain why severing the corpus callosum appears to lead to the development of two separate consciousnesses in split-brain patients.*"

Comment: You're right, it doesn't solve the 'other minds' problem. Nor does it begin by proving the reality of consciousness, which it takes for granted. It will always be impossible to prove that a robot is conscious, unless we cheat and redefine consciousness as something we can measure, a popular but philosophically hopeless approach. .

Comment: @PeterJ, in this sense we can't even measure selves consciousness, do we? If we do then why can't we measure robots' consciousness?

Comment: We can't measure it. There is no empirical method for detecting consciousness. It can only be inferred in other beings.

Comment: So whatever conclusions we derive from this, irrespective of their scientific value, won’t solve [the problem of zombies](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/zombies/) and we’ll be subject to the traditional [problems of induction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/induction-problem/) that have always characterized scientific theories. Yet, I’m intrigued by what value can the theory have if we can’t answer such fundamental questions.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo - I'm not sure what you mean by the zombie problem. Do you mean the 'hard' problem? The non-empirical nature of consciousness doesn't make this problem any harder or easier, It's always been the same. .

Comment: I thought this was interesting, and relevant: 'Two Top Theories To The Test: GNWT vs IIT' https://singularityhub.com/2021/06/02/whats-the-origin-of-consciousness-a-global-challenge-is-exploring-leading-theories/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIT is a proposal to explicate the concept of consciousness by information theory. More precisely, by a mathematical formalization and a prescript how to determine the degree of consciousness of an information system.

In a survey article, "Reggia, JA: The rise of machine consciousness: studying consciousness with computational models." (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23597599) compares four current approaches to study consciousness with a computational model. In characterizing IIT he writes:

> The basic idea is that the shared or mutual information among brain
>   regions that is above and beyond their information content as
>   individual regions enables them to interact in a constructive fashion.
>   This information integration is viewed as a neural correlate of
>   consciousness.

Like for any scientific theory, falsification or confirmation of the theory depends on comparing its consequences with observable facts. Here Regia comments on IIT:

> On the practical side, a major barrier to advancement in this area is
>   that one cannot apply φ directly to neural networks of appreciable
>   size. Further, a φ value alone does not really provide a meaningful
>   indication of whether consciousness is present or not: without a
>   golden standard such as the φ value for a typical human brain to use
>   as a comparison, it is extremely difficult to interpret what any given
>   value of φ actually means (Gamez, 2010). Such a measurement for real
>   brains is currently out of reach, not only because of the size of the
>   networks involved but also because our inability to precisely
>   characterize the detailed neural circuitry of the brain.

I can send you Reggia's full paper on request.

Comment: Very interesting. However, in the quote you present from this paper you highlight why scientists believe measuring consciousness is a difficult problem, but it is not yet clear to me what they’re actually measuring in IIT such that their scientific theory may be falsifiable.

Comment: The theory proposes a definition of φ and an algorithm to compute its value for a given information system. As an example of the test one has to check: To which degree does the computed φ-value match the degree of consciousness which is in general attributed to the given system. Note that several coherent definitions of consciousness exist, which are independent from IIT.